# How to avoid carrying malicious data hidden in a key

Tags: key-exchange, key-reuse

I'm going to ask a question and answer it, then hope someone has a better answer.

You are Bob, you have been given a large key by Alice (think 40 gigabytes on DVDs) to take with you to use for communicating while in a foreign country but first you will have to pass through their customs. Customs is looking for data that matches their most wanted list, they can scan through your data and lock you up if you have something they do not like, this list is not published. The country imposes heavy surveillance, and customs request that you open any encrypted files and will confiscate large random data files (except this one) and you can only be one person and enter the country once.

How can you be sure the key you are carrying is not on their most wanted data list? (How can you avoid being set up by Alice?)

Comment: This is a very odd scenario. Why would Bob want to carry out 40 giga of keys, instead of a 256 bits of seed and then uses key deviation functions to generate new keys? It is easy for Alice and Bob to agree on this seed without either party being able to control the output, for example, Diffie-Hellman. It is also easy to extract the randomness from the seed and then expand it to a string of keys.

Comment: @zhenfeizhang it could be for something that needs hardware generated random numbers not pseudo random numbers or CSPRNs. OTPs, gambling, physics simulations.

Comment: As it stands, the question is poorly conceived.  There are no 40 GB keys unless it's a one time pad.  You do not send your OTP through customs inspection.  No comms system worthy of a OTP requires 40 GB of it.  And physics simulations (think CERN) use the Twister for their randomness.  And what's the point of Alice setting you up?  The whole thing is extremely unclear and decisive to me.  Perhaps it's just me though...

Answer (score 1):

Bob has to be involved in the key creation process, he has to bring his own trusted hardware random number generator and ensure that while Alice is creating the key whenever she requires a random number his is also XORed with it. This is the data equivalent of packing your own suitcase.

Alice (or anyone that has a copy of the key) could still create any message and submit it to the customs agents, so Bob is at risk if Alice and customs collaborate in this way.